# How can I assign an absolute postition to <tr> elements in a <table> using Html and Css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give the rows in my table an absolute vertical position such that I can animate it using css "transition", but I'm having trouble with getting the rows to use the correct width.

My efforts so far look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border: solid 1px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    tbody {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      height: 96px;
      border: 1px dashed;
      width: 100%;
      left:0;
      right:0;
    }

    tr.absrow {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      border: dotted 1px;
    }

    td {
      border: solid 1px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="absrow" style="top: 0px;">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="absrow" style="top: 32px;">
        <td>Alice</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>alice@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="absrow" style="top: 64px;">
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>bob@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem: although the vertical sizes and positions appear to be working so far, the columns are not evenly sized, and the rows do not span the entire width of the table.

What are my options here? Do I have to assign a width manually to the individual columns, or can I still somehow rely on the automatic sizing by the browser (like with a nomral table)? And how do I make them span the width of the table?

**EDIT:**

I ended up using a list styled to look like a table. The result was NOT AT ALL helpful. I believed that the user would be able to track the rows if they were to visibly move from one place to another. Turns out, it yields so much moving stuff on the screen that that is impossible, and it jitters and lags quite badly as well. Instead, I simply opted for sorting the table when the user clicks a button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you need to use `position: absolute` for animation purposes but if you must use `position: absolute` then your only option is to specify the width for each column and make sure all the widths add up to 100%

Comment: Thanks. Are there alternatives to position: absolute? In the real application, the rows feature input fields, and are sorted based on the contents of one column. I found that users became confused when the rows suddenly jumped around (understandable), so that's why I'd like an animation. Most of those that I found were based on <ul> and <li>, where the <li> had a position:absolute, but I really like tables for their automatic formatting and semantic meaning.

Comment: Tables are not designed to work like this. You are also setting yourself up for some serious cross-browser compatibility issues.

Plus, even if it does work, you are going to be specifying the width for each of the cells anyway. So why not use `div`s or `ul`, `li`?